# Create pattern in datetime

Tags: python, datetime

Is there any simple way to create a pattern in datetime? If I have a timestamp that looks like this

```
2019-04-28 21:22:00
```

I could create a pattern in Java that looks like this

```
yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss
```

Is there something similar in Python?

Comment: check https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior

Comment: [Yes](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime.strftime#datetime.datetime.strftime).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Comment: From the current wording of the question, it's a bit hard to tell exactly what you're after here. Are you starting with a string and you want to end up with a datetime object or the other way around or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the [strftime](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) method of the `datetime` object from the datetime library.

In your case you would use the following format string:

```py
"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
```

Example usage:

```py
import datetime as dt

my_time = dt.datetime.now()
my_formatted_time = my_time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

print(my_formatted_time)
```

with result:

```
2019-04-28 12:30:46
```